# Magento 2 : Access image from Module's block

Tags: magento2, module, blocks, image

I want to access image from a Block in my custom module.  This is my current code:

```
public function getCustomtxt()
{
   $block->getViewFileUrl('images/Phone.jpg');
}
```

Comment: please Explain More What do you want ?

Comment: I  Created new Module. the image is stored in view\frontend\web\images\. I want to access the image in the block in my module

Comment: Hey use $this instade of $block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<img src="<?php echo $this->getViewFileUrl('images/Phone.jpg');?>" />
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<'

Answer (score 0):

Change to below code

Use `$this` instead `$block`

```
<?php echo $this->getViewFileUrl('images/Phone.jpg');?>
```

Comment: It displays URL of the image file. Not Displaying the image

Comment: @PrakashRaj Please check my answer

Comment: @PrakashRaj put this statement in img's src tag , like `<img src="myanswer">`

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to display image from image URL.

```
<img src="<?php echo $this->getViewFileUrl('images/footer-logo.png'); ?>" />
```